# How to edit the drop down menu at search page

Tags: search-layout

Can someone please suggest if is it possible to edit the menu options highlighted in the below image, I have created a new custom action and want to add it here?

[image]

Comment: No, you can only add buttons to the list view itself.

Comment: Thank you so much and also can I delete any one of the three options?

Comment: The menu options should be automatically generated based on user permissions; if you take away permission to delete, for example, the menu item will be removed.